# RUST compilation error: Expecting `::` instead got `{`

Tags: rust, compilation

I am new to rust, and I am trying to compile my code with this function:

```rust
fn recieve(&mut self, timeout: u64) -> <Vec<Vec<u8>>> {
        let mut bufs: Vec<Vec<u8>> = self.streams.iter().map(|_| Vec::new()).collect();
        task::block_on(future::join_all(self.streams.iter_mut().zip(bufs.iter_mut()).map(|(s, b)| {
            io::timeout(Duration::from_secs(timeout), s.read_to_end(b))
        })));
        Ok(bufs)
    }
```

I get this error:

```
error: expected `::`, found `{`
  --> src/lib.rs:60:59
   |
60 |     fn recieve(&mut self, timeout: u64) -> <Vec<Vec<u8>>> {
   |                                                           ^ expected `::`
```

What is the issue? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why are there `<` and `>` around the returned type ?

Comment: The returned type should probably be something like `Result<Vec<Vec<u8>>>` or  `Result<Vec<Vec<u8>>, SomeErrorType>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the angle-brackets surrounding the return type, and you should get past this problem.

Angle-brackets are only used in types to surround the argument provided to a generic type - they cannot surround any type like parentheses can surround any expression.